# How are the Drawer and the Back navigation button in the AppBar related?

Tags: flutter

How are the Drawer and the Back navigation button in the AppBar related?

There is a page

```
return Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    drawer: const AppDrawer(),
    appBar: PaginationAppBar(),
    body: SomeWidget(),
);
```

then in PaginationAppBar (which is actually AppBar) I use a button to open drawer

```
IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
    onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
),
```

BUT I had to use the following in AppBar to not show drawer Icon instead of back navigation button

```
automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
```

(otherwise there will be two drawer buttons in my appbar)

Can I use the approach shown above and show the Back navigation button in the AppBar at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter's widget implementations largely follow Material Design guidelines. The documentation states that AppBar should have only one leading navigation icon, alternating between the BackButton, Menu, or none. This design principle is detailed [here](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/guidelines#78ed9fd9-5664-40e0-ac51-69cb5de4952c)

If you're considering having two buttons in the leading section of the AppBar, remember that it goes against Material Design standards. This could potentially confuse users accustomed to the navigation style of Google's products.

Nevertheless, if you deem it necessary, you can design a custom AppBar to accommodate multiple leading icons. Here’s how you can do it:

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
final Widget child;
final double height;

CustomAppBar({
  required this.child,
  this.height = kToolbarHeight,
});

@override
Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Place your widgets here
  }
}
```

Also, when using a Drawer() in a Scaffold, it’s not essential to manually add a button to the AppBar or change automaticallyImplyLeading. Flutter automatically includes the menu button, adhering to the Material Design guidelines and ensuring user familiarity.

Comment: Probably you are right. having both the leading back button and a menu could be confusing, and in the meantime the is also a working hardware back button. But nevertheless I had to use automaticallyImplyLeading option because I used a drawer as an icon button and that's why flutter automatically replaced the back button with drawer button on the leading position withou using that option and as a result there were two drawer buttons in the appbar.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to show the menu and back icon at the same time.

Replace

```
IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
    onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
),
```

With

```
IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
),
```